# Have there been such an attempt made to make the comprehensive list of all New Testament scrolls ever found?

Tags: new-testament, archaeology, manuscript

Have there been any attempts made to make a comprehensive list of all scrolls or pieces of scrolls of the New Testament (in original languages) that have ever been discovered by archeologists?

Comment: How old? Which languages? Should the list include Syriac translations?, editions of the Vulgate?, the Book of Kells?, later printings of the Masoretic text?

Comment: @TRIG - I mean the original languages that the Bible was written in, not translations (Masoretic text i put into the category of "translations"). "How old?" - all that have been found.

Comment: @brilliant. They're [still being made](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2262/581).

Comment: @brilliant. It is a mitzvah to [write one's own Sefer Torah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10208/581), so there are countless thousands, many being written with quill and ink on parchment in houses and synagogues around the world right now this minute. So you're going to have to specify a cut-off date or find some other way to limit this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the New Testament, yes. Though Wikipedia may not be a "scholarly" source I find it good for this sort of thing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_manuscript#Listings

Also, in at least the [UBS](http://www.ubs-translations.org/cat/biblical_texts/greek_scriptures_and_reference/new_testament/) and [NA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novum_Testamentum_Graece), there is a list of manuscripts used to compile the "Greek New Testament." I think that the [BHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblia_Hebraica_Stuttgartensia) contains something somewhat similar for the Hebrew Bible.

Answer (score 2):

For the Greek Old Testament (i.e., "Septuagint"), there is also the *Verzeichnis der griechischen Handschriften des Alten Testaments* [= Catalogue of the Greek Manuscripts of the Old Testament], originally compiled by [Alfred Rahlfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Rahlfs) and published in 1914. It is available from [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/mitteilungendess00akaduoft), or in a hi-res PDF from the [Göttingen Septuaginta-Unternehmen](http://rep.adw-goe.de/handle/11858/00-001S-0000-0022-A312-7).

It was revised in 2004 by Detlef Fraenkel -- see the [SBL bookreview](https://www.bookreviews.org/pdf/5959_6334.pdf) for a description of the work, and the changes from Rahlfs' original edition.

[I know OP is interested in *New* Testament manuscripts, but this catalogue has many manuscripts that also contain NT material, and comments on the question suggest a slightly wider interest beyond the limits of the question as posed.]